# filenotfounderror: base_library.zip smtp pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, smtplib, file-not-found

I have built an python executable that has 3 main functions:
1) to copy files from one drive to another
2) then copy all those files from that other drive to a server
3) notify the user via an email that all the file syncing has been completed

Before I compile everything onto an executable the program runs well. But once I compile it into an .exe file with PyInstaller it always fails send the email because it cannot fin base_library.zip

Here is the full error message that I am getting. Any help would be much appreciate it.

Cheers

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\rafae\Desktop\AI
>   Projects\GUI\ExtraFunctions\RiBatch_FileDist\Aii_RiBatch_FileDist.py",
>   line 237, in    File "C:\Users\rafae\Desktop\AI
>   Projects\GUI\ExtraFunctions\RiBatch_FileDist\Aii_RiBatch_FileDist.py",
>   line 227, in main   File "C:\Users\rafae\Desktop\AI
>   Projects\GUI\ExtraFunctions\RiBatch_FileDist\Aii_RiBatch_FileDist.py",
>   line 171, in send_final_RiBatch_Email   File
>   "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py",
>   line 251, in **init**   File
>   "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py",
>   line 336, in connect   File
>   "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py",
>   line 307, in _get_socket   File
>   "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py",
>   line 704, in create_connection   File
>   "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py",
>   line 745, in getaddrinfo   File
>   "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings__init__.py",
>   line 100, in search_function   File "",
>   line 971, in _find_and_load   File "",
>   line 951, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 894, in _find_spec   File "", line 1157, in find_spec   File
>   "", line 1131, in _get_spec
>   File "", line 1112, in
>   _legacy_get_spec   File "", line 441, in spec_from_loader   File "", line
>   544, in spec_from_file_location FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such
>   file or directory: '\_MEI143482\base_library.zip'